# "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" appears when attempting to launch my app from a website using iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, iphone, redirect, mobile-safari

When I attempt to deep link to re-direct to my app from a website Safari presents an alert view asking **"Open in 'App Store'?"**

When the user selects **Open** they are shown another alert view saying:
**"Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"**

I am using iOS 10.3, and we suspect it may have started just in iOS 10.3 because this used to work in previous iOS versions. Has anyone else seen this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the code of script which is loaded for opening on AppStore? As if you are using iframe then it causes issue while loading in Safari from iOS 10.

Comment: are you on a real device or the simulator?  If you're trying to get to the store it won't work on the simulator.

Comment: @MikeM real device

Comment: As @Ellen said do share the code to diagnose more on this.!

Comment: @Ellen @satishiOS25 We have a javascript file that sets the location on the window object. An example of that would be: `window.location = <app_name>://<some_path_here>`

Comment: @joshrosenheck Have you fixed this issue?